# Compute Central Moments of Vector

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Say we have three stochastic variables defined as follows:

```
rho = NormalDistribution[rhom,sigmar];
beta = NormalDistribution[betam,sigmab];
alpha = NormalDistribution[alpham,sigmaa];
```

I would like to compute the central moments of the following vector containing functions of such variables:

```
ml={{rho/(Sqrt[1+Tan[alpha]^2+Tan[beta]^2]) Tan[alpha]},
    {rho/(Sqrt[1+Tan[alpha]^2+Tan[beta]^2]) Tan[beta]},
    {rho/(Sqrt[1+Tan[alpha]^2+Tan[beta]^2])}};
```

How can this task be fulfilled taking advantage of the definition of such `Distribution` objects?

Comment: Before looking further, you have not specified whether or not the random variables are independent. You have also not stated which central moments you seek.

Comment: Mathematica codes sprinkled in these CV threads might give you some ideas: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/144138/72352 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/144302/72352.

Comment: Because `rho` is involved in all of the random variables as a multiplicative factor, if `rho` is independent of both `alpha` and `beta`, then it would be best to concentrate on dealing with the distributions of the parts that deal with `alpha` and `beta`.  In other words this reduces the issue to dealing with just 2 random variables as adding an independent multiplicative random variable is easy to include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is not likely that Mathematica will return an analytical expression for such a complicated distribution. The form should be as follows, with a simpler [`TransformedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) of `rho+alpha+beta` and assuming variables are independent.

```
Assuming[
    And[
        Element[alpha | alpham | beta | betam | rho | rhom, Reals],
        Element[sigmaa | sigmab | sigmar, PositiveReals]
    ],
    With[
    {
        dist=TransformedDistribution[
            rho+alpha+beta
            , {
                Distributed[rho, NormalDistribution[rhom, sigmar]],
                Distributed[beta, NormalDistribution[betam, sigmab]],
                Distributed[alpha, NormalDistribution[alpham, sigmaa]]
            }
    ]
    },
    Table[CentralMoment[dist,n],{n,4}]
    ]
]
```

For me, this has been running for way too long without an answer:

```
Assuming[
    And[
        Element[alpha | alpham | beta | betam | rho | rhom, Reals],
        Element[sigmaa | sigmab | sigmar, PositiveReals]
    ],
    With[
    {
        dist=TransformedDistribution[
            rho/(Sqrt[1+Tan[alpha]^2+Tan[beta]^2]) Tan[alpha]
            , {
                Distributed[rho, NormalDistribution[rhom, sigmar]],
                Distributed[beta, NormalDistribution[betam, sigmab]],
                Distributed[alpha, NormalDistribution[alpham, sigmaa]]
            }
    ]
    },
    Table[CentralMoment[dist,n],{n,4}]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment to echo @rhermans answer:  I suspect the moments (and especially the pdf's) are unlikely to be found in a simple form even for a specified set of parameters.

Consider the following example (assuming that rho, beta, and alpha are all independent) for the first element in your vector:

```
n = 1000000;
SeedRandom[12345];
rho = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 1], n];
beta = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 3], n];
alpha = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[-2, 1/2], n];
d1 = rho/(Sqrt[1 + Tan[alpha]^2 + Tan[beta]^2]) Tan[alpha];
Histogram[d1, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF"]
```

[image: Histogram of samples from first element of desired vector of random variable]